# php form action link

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to edit the following php code to put it in the login form so when the user login he'll be redirected to his profile page.. 
here is the code that i am using to go to the profile page using a button ..

```
<li> <a style="background-color:rgb(40, 198, 218);" <?php echo '<a class="btn" href="'.site_url('show/agentproperties/'.$user_id).'">My Store</a>'; ?>
```

and i want to edit the form link to put the code above here

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('account/login');?>" method="post">
```

so how do we edit the form to include the 1st code instead of the code that's being used in the form right now.. which just redirects the user to the  home page ?

Regards.

Comment: header('location:profile.php'); is the easy way to redirect a user to his profile page if login doesnt fail

Answer (score 1):

have the page submit to itself (optional)

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

somewhere in the php located in the page, add something like

```
if($loggedIn){
    header('Location: '.site_url('account/login'));
    exit;
}
```

Comment: i want to use {.site_url('show/agentproperties/'.$user_id).} for the site url